# Trouble sending mms

Tags: ios, messages, iphone

I can text my son from my iphone5 but cannot send pics. He has android without internet can send fine to others. I am able to send him pics from my husband's iphone4 with upgrade toIOS7.1.

Comment: Which service providers are you on - some don't support photo messing

Comment: Also make sure you have turned Cellular Data on.

Comment: you probably need the update too